# moq object becomes null after assignment to controller

Tags: c#, tdd, moq, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am building a test for an MVC5 controller method.  I'm using moq for the test.  What I'm interested in is how to test a controller method that requires authentication and uses the userid value not the username value to make decisions about what data to show to the browser/client.

From what I have researched so far, there is a considerable amount of code available to moq the username, but not much code for the userid value (in my case that looks like a Guid).  I'm using ASP.Net Identity as the account management.  I have OWIN added as well for Google and Facebook login.

I'm using dependency injection (using Unity) because it seems that that is about the only way to accomplish tests, plus DI enables the use of moq.

Here is an example of the test method that is looking for a 'NotNull' return from the controller method:

```
Mock<ModelObject> CreateModelObjectFromHelper()
{
    var ci = new Mock<ClaimsIdentity>();
    var myHelper = new Mock<MyHelper>();
    myHelper.Setup(x => x.GetCurrentUserId(ci.Object)).Returns("333c188b-b33a-4233-83bd-5ea3a3333333");
    return new Mock<ModelObject>(myHelper.Object);
}


[TestMethod]
public async Task ExampleController_Method_NotNull()
{
    Mock<ModelObject> o = CreateModelObjectFromHelper();
    ExampleController controller = new ExampleController(o.Object as IModelObject);
    ViewResult result = await controller.MethodName() as ViewResult;
    //check for non null result
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

The GetCurrentUserId method is where I query the User.Identity object for the userid using this code:

```
var userIdClaim = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
userIdValue = userIdClaim.Value.ToString();
```

And the method is supposedly getting replaced by moq.  The GetCurrentUserId method is a virtual method in a helper class (MyHelper) that is the parameter of the constructor for the model object (ModelObject) that is the parameter of the constructor for the controller (ExampleController).

What happens in the debugger (Visual Studio 2013) for the test method is that the objects are created in the CreateModelObjectFromHelper method, but when the ExampleController is created at the line:

```
ExampleController controller = new ExampleController(o.Object as IModelObject);
```

The MyHelper moq'd object becomes null.  I can see the object has a value before this statement, but at this statement, the MyHelper object becomes null...and the whole test fails.  I assume it fails because it is difficult to call methods on an object that is null.

The question is...what causes this object to become null?

The other question is...maybe there is a better way to do this and if so, I'd sure be glad to hear a suggestion.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work like that. You try to create mock of a mock of a mock ...

If your controller depend only on the IModelObject, then only create Mock and set it's properties/methods to return what you need in the controller.

Without the code for IModelObject, and how it is used in the controller, it's hard to provide better example.